# Interpreting memory usage in htop

Tags: linux, memory, htop

Trying to diagnose a memory issue using `htop`. As can be seen on the `Mem`-bar at the top, 9.05 out of 9.5 GB is used.

**Question 1:** How do I determine what's eating up all my memory?

The output from `htop` seems to indicate that the Java process at the top is the biggest culprit, but at the same time it only consumes 15.6%! It doesn't add up!

**Question 2:** How should I interpret the output from `htop`?

[image]

Comment: when in doubt, close all interactive apps and revisit.

Comment: I could also restart the computer. This clever little tip doesn't address my question though.

Comment: Your sarcasm is misplaced. If yo do not know what is eating up your RAM, start closing processes one by one and re-check after each of them. But if you restart your system, you loose the chance to detect what exactly was the cause. HTH.

Comment: I happen to know which process it was in this case. It was a chomium browser living inside a Java application (jxbrowser). But I'd like to understand the htop output for future debugging. Closing applications one by one is not always an option!

Comment: Great, then use `man htop`

Comment: Already have. It doesn't answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that the question is not clear.  It reads as a specific _What is my problem?_ question.  Whereas you are trying, but not really succeeding, to ask a general _How do I actually **use this tool** to diagnose such problem**s**?_ question.  You've buried that at the end.  It needs to be more prominent in the question, and not seemingly a subordinate afterthought.

Comment: @JdeBP, clarified question. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: add output of `free -h`

Comment: @Kiwy, unfortunately this situation arose almost 2 weeks ago. I've restarted the machine since. Will update with `free -h` if I run into it again. This screenshot is all I have left from that particular situation unfortunately.

Comment: feel free to update your question if it happen again, but in the current situation it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Kiwy, surely it can't be impossible to explain the seemingly inconsistent information given by `htop`? I'm not after what happened in this exact situation. This is rather a general question about `htop` (and how to generally diagnose this type of strange situation).

Comment: @aioobe there could be dozens of explanation going from a bug in your version of htop to small program forking using 1Mo of RAM each time. Problem is you can't provide the information at the moment opf the issue. So If you want help edit your question but in it's current form it isn't possible to tell you.

Comment: @Kiwy, I highly doubt it's a bug in `htop`. I'm sure there's a natural explanation. Now regarding the 1Mo of RAM each time, wouldn't that add up to gigabytes of ram, and show up on top of the output? Or are you suggesting that I had thousands of small processes further down in the htop window?

Comment: Well, do the math. Your image shows 11½ processes out of 131.  The top 11 add up to 68%. If the bottom 120 processes (131−11) use an average of 0.25% of the memory, that’s another 30%, for a total of 98%. The 12th process can be seen to be 1.1, so the bottom 120 could all be that large. So, yes, it seems quite possible that 131 processes are using 95% of the system memory, even though the largest is only 15.6%.